# How to access "Manage wireless networks" in acer netbook (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, control-panel, acer-aspire-one

I have windows 7 prof on a aspire acer one netbook.
I want to access the "Manage wireless networks" panel from 
Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Manage wireless networks (on the left bar)

I click it, but it just won't open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some ACER Network manager software (which overrides the Windows one) that failed to install correctly?

Comment: I formated the notebook again, and it works fine now.
Maybe something was wrong in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Click 'Start'. In the search box, type in 'Manage Wireless Networks'. This is a shortcut that should also launch the manager.

If this also fails, then there is a problem in your Win7 installation or something is corrupt.

Comment: That doesn't work :(

Is there any way to find out what's wrong?